# Can you amend UICollectionView scrollDirection programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, scroll, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that is created using Storyboard (given it has quite complicated cells).  I want to programmatically change the scrollDirection to be horizontal (on 4 inch screens) and vertical (on 3.5 inch screens).

I see you can set scrollDirection upon initiation, but I cannot see how you can access this property from an already created UICollectionView.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: You may need to create a for loop, and find the UIScrollView that you need within the UICollectionView and cast it's delegate to your view controller (if you want to be aware of when this scroll scrolls, drags, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout
```

This is how you would go about using it

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *horizontalLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
horizontalLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;

[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:horizontalLayout];
```

I assume that your collectionView is linked with the storyboard as self.collectionView

This is the quick and dirty way. What you should do is create your own layout and subclass the UICollectionViewFlowLayout class.

An example can be found here: [UICollectionViewFlowLayoutExample by AshFurrow](https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionViewFlowLayoutExample)

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thank you very much for this answer.  The problem with this approach is I seem to lose the UICollectionViewFlowLayout properties that were set by storyboard (i.e. layout, etc).  Any way around this?

Comment: I edited the answer and hope that this works for you now. Otherwise have a look at the Link, since this approach is a bit dirty